# <Outlet /> fails to rerender with react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In the following code, the url changes but the content doesn't rerender until manual refresh. What am I doing wrong here? I could use props.children or something but don't really want to. My understanding of  is that it should render the content of the nested  elements under .

```
const LandingPage = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    buttons
                    <Button>
                        <Link to="/team1">team1</Link>
                    </Button>
                    <Button>
                        <Link to="/team2">team2</Link>
                    </Button>
                    <Button>
                        <Link to="/team3">team3</Link>
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <Outlet />
            </div>
        )
}

export default class Router extends Component<any> {

    state = {
        teams: [team1, team2, team3] as Team[]
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<LandingPage />} >
                        {
                            this.state.teams.map(team => {
                                const path = `/${team.name.toLowerCase()}`
                                return (
                                    <Route path={path} element={
                                        <BaseTeam
                                            name={team.name}
                                            TL={team.TL}
                                            location={team.location}
                                            members={team.members}
                                            iconPath={team.iconPath}
                                        />
                                    } />)
                            })
                        }
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure teams is defined in the router state when the landing page is loaded? So not when you're navigating a teams page/link.

Comment: @CasperKuethe when I click on the first button, it loads correctly, i.e. url is /team1 and the content of team1 shows up. But clicking on the buttons afterwards changes the url but not the content

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is here. Can you provide a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live? There *is* a missing React key on the mapped `Route` component though.

Comment: @DrewReese the process of creating the sandbox led me to fix it --- the issue was resolved when I remove the constructor from the BaseTeam component and just render this.props.name correctly. Not sure why that's happening though. Check out the sandbox to see the nonfunctional version https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-silence-8svo9v?file=/src/baseteam.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the mapped routes are missing a React key. Add `key={path}` so each route is rendering a different instance of `BaseTeam`.

The main issue is that the `BaseTeam` component is the same "instance" for all the routes rendering it.

It should either ***also*** have a `key` prop specified so when the key changes `BaseTeam` is remounted and sets the `name` class property.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />}>
      {this.state.teams.map((team) => {
        const path = `/${team.name.toLowerCase()}`;
        return (
          <Route
            key={path} // <-- add missing React key
            path={path}
            element={(
              <BaseTeam
                key={path} // <-- add key to trigger remounting
                name={team.name}
              />
            )}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

[image: Edit outlet-fails-to-rerender-with-react-router-v6]

Or `BaseTeam` needs to be updated to react to the `name` prop updating. Use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to check the `name` prop against the current state, enqueue a state update is necessary.

Example:

```
class BaseTeam extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: this.props.name
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.name !== this.props.name) {
      this.setState({ name: this.props.name });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

...

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />}>
      {this.state.teams.map((team) => {
        const path = `/${team.name.toLowerCase()}`;
        return (
          <Route
            key={path}
            path={path}
            element={<BaseTeam name={team.name} />}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

[image: Edit outlet-fails-to-rerender-with-react-router-v6 (forked)]

As you've found out in your code though, just rendering the `props.name` prop directly is *actually* the correct solution. It's a React anti-pattern to store passed props into local state. As you can see, it requires extra code to keep the props and state synchrononized.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe signal to react library that a key has changed so that it needs to rerender the outlet

```
const LandingPage = () => {
    const location = useLocation(); // react-router-dom
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                buttons
                <Button>
                    <Link to="/team1">team1</Link>
                </Button>
                <Button>
                    <Link to="/team2">team2</Link>
                </Button>
                <Button>
                    <Link to="/team3">team3</Link>
                </Button>
            </div>
            <Outlet key={location.pathname}/>
        </div>
    )}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used nested routes with outlet then the below code will work

```
<Outlet key={Date.now()} />
```